# SQL - Find duplicate children

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table containing meetings:

```
MeetID      Description
-----------------------------------------------------
1           SQL Workshop
2           Cake Workshop
```

I have another table containing all participants in the meetings:

```
PartID      MeetID      Name          Role
-----------------------------------------------------
1           1           Jan           Coordinator
2           1           Peter         Participant
3           1           Eva           Participant
4           1           Michael       Coordinator
5           2           Jan           Coordinator
6           2           Peter         Participant
```

I want to find is a list of all meetings that have 2 or more participants with Role = 'Coordinator'. 
Eg. in the example above that would be the meeting with MeetID=1 and not 2.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this, allthough I think it should be simple :-) 
(I am using SQL Server 2012)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy to do using `group by` and `having`:

```
select MeetId
from participants p
where Role = 'Coordinator'
group by MeetId
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Note:  `Role` is a [potential keyword/reserved word](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.110).aspx), so it is a bad choice for a column name.

Comment: Thanks (and I am aware of the role-problem :-) )
This is also what I was trying, but for some reason I get no results - allthough I know there are meetings like this in the db.
I may have simplified the question too much, - I'll rethink it and get back :-)

Comment: Aargh,  - typo on my account :-)
This code works if I use correct fieldnames :-) 
Thanks for forcing me to triple-check my code :-)